# MSBUILD MSB4075

Tags: visual-studio-2008, msbuild

I converted my VS2005 to VS2008 and I get the following error:

error MSB4075: The project file must be opened in the Visual Studio IDE and converted to the latest version before it can be built by MSBuild.

Any help appreciated. Google failed me this time lol..

Comment: Its not clear whether you have actually opened said project in the IDE yet?

Comment: Yes I have converted the solution and project in VS2008. The weird thing is that it works locally on my PC running Vista. The error is happening on our build server with window 2003.

Comment: The MSBuild I used is in the 3.5 window framework dir. I read somewhere that it has something to do with csproj.user file. I have not checked it in our build server. Will do so later.

Answer (score 2):

It sounds like you converted the solution, but not the project file. Maybe the project file was unloaded when you did the conversion? At any rate, try opening the project file in Visual Studio and let it convert it.

Comment: Anyway my issue was resolved. In our build bat file it has a call to copy over csproj.user file for each project. MSBuild will then automatically assume that it needs conversion. Hope this will help someone out there. Thanks all..

Comment: Also removing the offending reference and adding it back again in the project properties might help.

Answer (score 1):

Like Odez said in his comment, I also got this error because of .user files.
In my case it was an older converted project which got the .user files checked in when converting to svn. Removing them from version control fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

Rob Prouse is right - it sounds like the project file hasn't been converted. If you can't follow his advice to convert the project file for some reason, you should be able to run the old version of MSBuild manually. MSBuild is installed with the .NET framework, and should be found at *%WinDir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MSBuild.exe*. From memory, the command line is just "MSBuild *ProjectFilename*".