# MSBuild error when building projects for the first time

Tags: .net, msbuild, build-automation

When i try to run my MSBuild script for a project before opening it in IDE, I get this error:

> "The project file must be opened in
>   the Visual Studio IDE and converted to
>   the latest version before it can be
>   built by MSBuild"

What's the reason i'm getting this error?

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/444857/msbuild-msb4075/445039

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution and/or project files are set for one version of visual studio and MSBuild is building them as a different version.  If you look in a solution file you're going to see something like this:

> Microsoft Visual Studio Solution File,
>   Format Version 10.00
>    # Visual Studio 2008

The format version & visual studio # are going to vary based on whether you're using VS2003, VS2005, VS2008 and assumingly VS2010.

On your command line, where you're launching the build, it is launched from a specific version of the .NET framework:

> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\MSBuild

Comment: My .proj is written in vs 2005 and i try to run the MSBuild script from the "v2.0.50727" framework path. Is anything wrong here? When i build the proj first time in IDE and then run the scrit, error goes away.

Comment: Your IDE is likely updating the project or build files for you, without informing you of that change.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `DevEnv.exe` from the command line with the `/Upgrade` switch if you wish to do this as part of some automated process.

Answer (score 0):

I'm having this very same trouble.

I've run the /upgrade on every single .csproj file but it persists.

Edit: I've solved it !

- I deleted all the Temporary ASP.NET Files

  I deleted spurious files within my project folder

  I ran "devenv myProject.csproj" on **ALL** project files.

  I manually deleted all the DLLs produced by my project

  I opened in notepad++ my .csproj files, both converted and the "nonconverted rebels" and then compared them and tried to make the conversion by hand (changing version numbers etc.)

Sometime it worked and I'm not even sure why... (cargo-cult programming)

Answer (score 0):

I simply re-added the references, and it worked.

My case was that I just migrated a NET1.1 web application into NET4.

So as is, I tried to compile and that showed me this error.